# asp image button refreshes page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi My web page has lots of imageButtons, which refresh the page on click. How do I prevent this?

```
 var imageButton = new ImageButton();
    imageButton.ImageUrl = "Styles/unClicked.png";
    imageButton.ID = "btn" + questionName;
     imageButton.OnClientClick = ("javascript:button_pressed()");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer would be that if you don't want the image to post-back, don't use `<asp:ImageButton`> and just use an `<img>` element.

But if you want to use the `<asp:ImageButton>` then update the following line to stop the page being posted-back (refreshed)...

```
imageButton.OnClientClick = "button_pressed();return false;"
```

Note, that you do not need the initial "javascript:" (the browser knows it's javascript)

Comment: You're welcome @gemini, good luck with the rest of your project :-)